# Общие классы в WCF сервисах

Tags: c#, wcf

Имеется ряд wcf-сервисов, методы которых возвращают коллекцию объектов одного типа. Объект описан в библиотеке, подключаемой ко всем сервисам.
Однако если мы хотим агрегировать результаты вызова всех сервисов, получаем, что каждый возвращает коллекцию своего типа.
Какие есть варианты решения задачи агрегирования результата? Или придется переделывать методы сервисов на возврат JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема возникает лишь по той причине, что вы генерируете все клиенты к сервисам независимо. Вместо этого, можно

**Вариант 1.** Загрузите все описания сервисов в формате wsdl, после чего слейте их в один, убрав повторения. По полученному wsdl и стройте клиент. Теперь все клиенты используют общие типы.

**Вариант 2.** Подключите ту самую библиотеку, в которой описаны общие типы, к клиенту - после чего перегенерируйте клиентов, не забыв включить флажок "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" (или как он там называется). Тогда сгенерированные клиенты будут использовать типы из этой библиотеки.

**Вариант 3.** Если есть возможность вынести в общую библиотеку не только типы данных, но и интерфейсы - то даже не придется ничего генерировать.

**Вариант 4.** Если все совсем плохо - то ведь клиентские типы данных и интерфейсы можно и ручками написать - главное им поставить правильные аттрибуты (которые можно подглядеть в автосгенерированном коде).

Comment: Вариант 1 в данном случае подходит, однако, при частых изменениях в сервисах, поддерживать данное решение будет не совсем удобно. Варианты 2 и 3 подходят, только если все сервисы и клиент находятся в одном решении, что в моем случае не так.

Comment: Библиотеку можно подключать и отдельным файлом, не обязательно проектом в решении. Это уже вопрос управления зависимостями.

Comment: Можно, в этом случае получаем описанную изначально проблему. Пока остановился на варианте с конвертором к общему типу, за счет рефлексии. С возможным дальнейшим переходом на Вариант 1. Спасибо за помощь.